# has_parent does not work when parent and cihld index types are same in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to design a comment/reply system in `ElasticSearch` using [parent/child](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-parent-field.html). If I use separate types like `/twitter/tweet` and `/twitter/reply` both `has_parent` and `has_child` query and filters works. However, when I store all messages in `/twitter/tweet` and set mapping as below only `has_child` query works, since `has_parent` does not work I am not able to reach replies belongs to specific tweet. Is it wrong to create a `parent/child` relation on same document type of an index?

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_mapping -d '{
"tweet":{
 "_parent": {"type": "tweet"}
}
}'
```

Comment: We have run into the same issue recently, could it be a bug in ElasticSearch?

Comment: I do not know, I leave this project and had no solution for this problem.